# Creating Animations like a mobile app in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

This might be a stupid question but is there a way to create animations like mobile app in the browser. 
Ref link: http://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/meaningful-transitions.html#meaningful-transitions-meaningful-transitions-examples

It would be great if something could be built like this. I know a bit of javascript/jquery but this seems to be way out of my knowledge.

Any technical details would be helpful

Comment: Are you trying to create an HTML5 app for a phone? If so I'll inform you that I've already tried that and the animations don't work as smoothly as they do in native.

Comment: Also you might want to look at the other examples on the same link you've provided. Thoroughly check out everything in the animation section.

Comment: I am trying to build a website with these animations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using famo.us:  http://famo.us/

It's a new framework so there are some issues but it has potential.  It relies on matrix transforms and can do really amazing things such as this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6jg-PlisAFc

You can check out more demos here: http://famo.us/demos/

And there is a DNA helix example here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbIL3asjZBs

Hope this helps.

Comment: This looks great, can I do this in a browser?

Comment: Ok, its built on javascipt, so I assume it can implemented in brower

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little example of what you can do with a bit of jQuery to trigger the animation with a class change and CSS3 transitions to handle the animation.

It will need some tweaking and customizing to reach the quality of the linked animations but it shows that CSS3/jQuery animations can be pretty smooth.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/6yk9c/)**

*HTML :*

```
<header></header>
<section>
    <article>
        <div class="wrap">
            <img src="" alt="" />
            <p>some text</p>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <div class="wrap">
            <img src="" alt="" />
            <p>some text</p>
        </div>
    </article>
    ....
</section>
```

*CSS :*

```
body,html{margin:0;}
header{
    height:100px;
    background:#000;
}
article{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    padding-bottom:16%;
    position:relative;
    color:#fff;
}
article .wrap{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:1;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);

    -webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease-out, height 0.2s ease-out, 1s z-index 0s;
    transition: width 0.2s ease-out, height 0.2s ease-out, 1s z-index 0s;
}
article .wrap img{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
footer{
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#000;
}
article:nth-child(odd) .wrap.show{
    width:200%;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index:2;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease-out, height 0.6s ease-out;
    transition: width 0.2s ease-out, height 0.6s ease-out;
}
```

*jQuery :*

```
$('.wrap').click(function(){
    $('.wrap').not(this).removeClass('show');
    $(this).toggleClass('show');
});
```

Comment: thank you for the demo, this definitely needs lots of tweaking for each animation.

Comment: @user3486430 yes, this is just quick a start, quality animations always need a lot of work... But I wanted to highlight that you can make them with simple tools and don't need tons of plugins.